# I can not make the buttons workable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a page with 2 questions with yes/no button using jQuery. I have used jQuery fade in/out options for this. But the buttons are not working. Can anyone help me with that??

I have given all the codes of my page with CSS and jQuery.

jQuery:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".qusone").click(function () {
            $(".one").fadeOut(100);
            $(".two").delay(100).fadeIn(100);


        });

        $(".qustwo").click(function () {
            $(".two").fadeOut(100);
            $(".three").delay(100).fadeIn(100);

        });
        $(".qusthree").click(function () {
            $(".three").fadeOut(100);
            $(".full1").delay(2200).fadeIn(100);

        });

        $(".qusfour").click(function () {
            $(".full1").fadeOut(100, Function() {

                $(".four").delay(100).fadeIn(100);

            });

        });

    });
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #EEF3FA;
    text-shadow: none;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
.fix {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
header {
    background: #49639C;
    text-align: center;
}
section {} footer {
    text-align: center;
}
.main {
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.head {} .head > h1 {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.sec {
    background: #6281B6;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
}
.sec > h2 {
    background: url("../img/prize.png") no-repeat scroll left 80px center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px;
}
.sec > h2 > span {
    color: #E8ED1A;
}
.cove {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.congrts {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 35px 15px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.congrts > h1 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: -30px auto 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 280px;
    color: #000000;
}
.congrts > p {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 5px 15px 8px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #000000;
}
.congrts > p > strong {} .prizes {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 35px 15px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.prizes > h1 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: -30px auto 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 280px;
    color: #000000;
}
.item {
    border-bottom: 2px dashed #cccccc;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 60px;
}
.img {} .img > img {
    width: 250px;
}
.text > h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.text > p {
    font-size: 35px;
}
.text > span {
    color: #FF0000;
    font-size: 35px;
}
.text {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.anchor {
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.anchor > a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #6bb155;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 10px 164px;
    text-align: center;
}
.anchor > a:hover {
    text-shadow: none;
}
.fotter {
    margin: 10px 0px;
}
.heiighrt {
    height: 580px;
}
.kolo {
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.kolo > h1 {
    color: #3B5998;
    font-size: 35px;
}
.kolo > p {
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.kolo > p > strong {}.span {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    color: #666666;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.kolo1 {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ffffff;
}
.pok {
    margin: 15px auto;
    width: 500px;
}
.pok > img {
    float: left;
}
.pok > p {
    float: left;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.anchortext {
    margin: 5px auto;
}
.anchortext > a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #6bb155;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding: 2px 150px;
}
.anchortext1 {
    margin: 5px auto;
}
.anchortext1 > a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #6bb155;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 1px 70px;
}
.up1 {
    padding: 2px 157px !important;
}
.up2 {
    padding: 2px 143px !important;
}
.full {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.full h1 {
    color: #3c599d;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.full h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.full h2 span {
    color: #3C599D;
}
.full1 {
    text-align: center;
}
.full1 img {
    margin-top: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
}
.qus {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.two, .three, .four, .load, .ditiyo, .titiyo, .chortor{display:none;}
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <header>
        <div class="main head fix">
            <h1>Message</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section>

        <div class="main fix">
            <div class="heiighrt one">

                <div class="kolo">
                    <h1>We Need Your Comment</h1>
                    <p>We've selected you from 1,873,235 <strong>Mac mobile users in Australia</strong> to comment on a new app. The great news is you'll have a chance to <strong>win a cool iPad mini after this!</strong>
                    </p>
                    <p class="span">* Only 2 questions and take just 15 secs!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="kolo1">

                    <div class="pok fix">
                        <img src="img/ipad.png" alt="ipad on hand">
                        <p>Do you use Fb
                            <br>everyday?</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="qusone">
                    <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                        <div class="ui-grid-a anchortext"><a href="#" class="prothom">Yes</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                        <div class="ui-grid-a anchortext"><a href="#" class="up1 prothom">No</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="heiighrt two">
            <div class="full fix">
                <h1>Question 1</h1>
                <h2>Have You ever heard of <br><span>Facebook Home</span>?</h2>
                <div class="qustwo">
                    <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                        <div class="ui-grid-a anchortext1"><a href="#" class="up2 ditiyo">Yes, i know</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                        <div class="ui-grid-a anchortext1"><a href="#" class="ditiyo">No, Never Heard of</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <img src="img/ipad.png" alt="i pad on hand">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="heiighrt three">

            <div class="full fix">
                <h1>Question 1</h1>
                <h2>If you get a new iPad mini,<br>will you install<span>Facebook <br>Home</span>?</h2>
                <div class="qusthree">
                    <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                        <div class="ui-grid-a anchortext1"><a href="#" class="up2 titiyo">Yes, I love to</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                        <div class="ui-grid-a anchortext1"><a href="#" class="titiyo">No, I don't like FB</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <img src="img/ipad.png" alt="i pad on hand">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="heiighrt load">

            <div class="full1 fix">

                <img src="img/loading.gif" alt="i pad on hand">


            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="heiighrt four">

            <div class="full full1 fix">
                <h1>Thank You</h1>
                <h2>You've helped in creating better apps for mobile users! Please proceed to see if<br> you will<br><strong>win the New iPad mini!</strong> </h2>
                <img src="img/ipad.png" alt="i pad on hand">
                <div class="qusfour">
                    <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                        <div class="ui-grid-a anchortext1"><a href="#" class="up2 chortor">I am feeling lucky Today!</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <footer>
        <div class="main">
            <p class="fotter">copyright 2013 <a href="#">Terms</a> 
                <a href="#">Privacy</a>
            </p>

        </div>
    </footer>
```

[Here the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4cf5r4m/)

Comment: Try [jshint](http://www.jshint.com/). `Function` isn't valid...

Comment: i might be blind, but i cant seems to see either .one or .two classes

Comment: Looking at your javascript it looks like you have set the click even on the div ".qusone" instead of the anchor tag's of yes and no. Is that intentional?

Comment: Hey Gjohn actually i am kinda new with using these jquery options. So, I don't know exactly what to write. I have learned to using this option from another page. can you tell me what should i need to write?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to want to bind your buttons that are hidden then my suggstion would be to switch to the following format

```
$(document).on('click', '.qustwo', function() { ...your code here... });
```

That should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your script by this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".qusone").click(function () {
                $(".one").fadeOut(100);
                $(".two").fadeIn(100);


            });

            $(".qustwo").click(function () {
                $(".two").fadeOut(100);
                $(".three").delay(100).fadeIn(100);

            });
            $(".qusthree").click(function () {
                $(".three").fadeOut(100);
                $(".full1").delay(2200).fadeIn(100);

            });

            $(".qusfour").click(function () {
                $(".full1").fadeOut(100);
                $(".four").delay(100).fadeIn(100);

            });

        });
```

You still need to clean up your code though to get intended flow.